# "for i:=0 to i" loop in Pascal - why does it work?

Tags: loops, pascal

I'm surprised nobody ask this yet, because it's something I noticed a long time ago.

Apparently, in Pascal, you can use the same variable for both a loop counter, and a number of repetitions. The following two pieces of code:

```
i := 10;
for i:= 0 to i do
begin;
    write(i);
end;
```

and

```
for i:= 0 to 10 do
begin;
    write(i);
end;
```

appear to be equivalent, as both print `012345678910`.

Why does it work, and why **doesn't** it work in other languages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works because, in Pascal, the end value of the loop is **only evaluated once**, i.e. the value of `i` is taken at the time the loop is entered.

In other words, the Pascal code is **as if** you had done:

```
someHelpVar := i;
for i := 0 to someHelpVar do
```

and that, in its turn, is equivalent to:

```
someHelpVar := i;
i := 0;
while i <= someHelpVar do
begin
  ...
  i := i + 1; // or Inc(i);
end;
```

In other languages, e.g. C, if you do:

```
for (i = 0; i <= i; i++)
```

you are not doing the same. The end value is *re-evaluated on each iteration*, i.e. not only once. The code above is like:

```
i = 0;
while (i <= i)
{
    ...
    i++;
}
```

Since that while condition is always true, you get an endless loop.

---

So, to summarize: *in Pascal, the end value is evaluated only once and stored in an unnamed temporary variable. **This means that the end condition does not change with `i`**. In other languages, it is re-evaluated on each iteration, and not only once.*

#### Note:

Doing something like

```
  i := 10;
  for i := 0 to i do
```

is frowned upon, because even though it works, it is confusing for the reader. Rather use a different variable as the loop index:

```
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  i := 10;
  for j := 0 to i do
```

As they say: "*Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.  Code for readability.*" Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c++/rYCO5yn4lXw/oITtSkZOtoUJ